# Utility service that logs total network usage

Tags: networking, performance, bandwidth, wireshark

I would like to know the total bandwidth our internet provider essentially provides to the many competing devices in our home. Is there a simple windows service that uses a wireshark like trick to log total bandwidth usage over time of all devices on a single machine (and maybe, as a perk, also breaks it down by device)? Wireshark per se isn't what I am after as it logs all packets and I just want total bandwidth which takes far less log space. Also wireshark requires restarting on each boot, and I would like this just accumulated over time.

My impression is that even when a low pressure synchronization is taking place over a long time our ISP is throttling us (i.e. streaming video becomes almost non functional if skydrive has been running its slowly syncing of data over a long time, or if a very slow but very long download is taking place), but I would like to verify this and with a lot of devices running here and there it is hard to confirm without real logging.

Comment: you might be able to do this at your router, so including that information may help - I'm wondering if something like rflow might be the answer